# Ignore a field in a query if the field doesn't exist or is null?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm using the following query :

```
$and : [
        {$where : 'function(){if(this.vehicle.class){return this.vehicle.class == "Car";};return true;}'},
        {$where : 'function(){if(this.vehicle.make){return this.vehicle.make == "MERCEDES-BENZ";};return true;}'},
        {$where : 'function(){if(this.vehicle.model){return this.vehicle.model == "320";};return true;}'},
        {$where : 'function(){if(this.price && this.price.min){return this.price.min >= 1000;};return true;}'},
        {$where : 'function(){if(this.price && this.price.max){return this.price.max <= 1000;};return true;}'}
    ]
```

is the a more elegant way to ignore field in a query if the field ist not set or is null? With native mongo query operators ?

Answer (score 4):

To ignore fields that either do not exist or are null, you need to make use of combination the `$exists` and the `$type` query operators.

> $exists:
>
> Syntax: { field: { $exists: `<boolean>` } }
>   When `<boolean>` is true, $exists matches the documents that contain the
>   field, including documents where the field value is null. If `<boolean>`
>   is false, the query returns only the documents that do not contain the
>   field.
>
> $type:
>
> $type selects the documents where the value of the field is the
>   specified BSON type

```
BSON types:

Null    10
Double  1
String  2
```

To see all the valid BSON types in mongodb refer: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/

for example the below mongo query would fetch those documents where the field `vehicle.class` `exists` and contains data which is of type `String`.

```
db.collection.find({"vehicle.class":{$exists:true,$type:2}})
```

Where `type 2` denotes, String and `type 10` denotes `null`. We would want to find those records where the type of data stored in vehicle.class, if it exists, is `String`, rather than `null`.

For `Double`, the `type` is `1`, by default the datatype of Numbers stored in mongodb is 'Double'.

```
db.collection.find({"price.max":{$exists:true,$type:1}})
```

The output you want can be obtained as follows, using a combination of `$and`and `$or` with `$exists` and `$type`.

```
db.collection.find({
$and:[{$or:[{"price.max":{$lte:1000}},{"price.max":{$exists:false}},{"price.max":{$type:10}}]},
{$or:[{"price.min":{$gte:1000}},{"price.min":{$exists:false}},{"price.min":{$type:10}}]},
{$or:[{"vehicle.model":{$in:["320"]}},{"vehicle.model":{$exists:false}},{"vehicle.model":{$type:10}}]},
{$or:[{"vehicle.make":{$in:["MERCEDES-BENZ"]}},{"vehicle.make":{$exists:false}},{"vehicle.make":{$type:10}}]},
{$or:[{"vehicle.class":{$in:["Car"]}},{"vehicle.class":{$exists:false}},{"vehicle.class":{$type:10}}]}]
})
```

Comment: "vehicle.model":{$exists:true,$type:2,$in:["320"]}
will the field be ignored if the key doesn't exist at all ?

Comment: Great answer, but it has antoher effect not like the code i've wrote above in the question. If the field doesn't exist it must not be used in the query condition at all.

Comment: @dima - have modified my answer to be more specific.